# Comparing groups of rows in Pandas Dataframe that share a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe containing a name column and and a numerical column.

```
0 name number
1 a    3
2 a    6
3 b    2
4 b    500
5 c    349
6 c    200
```

What I want to do is define a new column that shows the numerical difference between two sequential rows that have the same name. This can be outputted onto the first row of the comparison I.e.:

```
0 name number diff
1  a    3     3
2  a    6     N/A
3  b    2     498
4  b    500   N/A
5  c    349   149
6  c    200   N/A
```

What is the best way of doing this using Pandas? As a bonus, if there is more than two rows with the same name, I want the highest numbered row compared against the lowest value row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('name')['number'].diff().abs()
print (df)
   0 name  number   diff
0  1    a       3    NaN
1  2    a       6    3.0
2  3    b       2    NaN
3  4    b     500  498.0
4  5    c     349    NaN
5  6    c     200  149.0
```

Or:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('name')['number'].diff(-1).abs()
print (df)
   0 name  number   diff
0  1    a       3    3.0
1  2    a       6    NaN
2  3    b       2  498.0
3  4    b     500    NaN
4  5    c     349  149.0
5  6    c     200    NaN
```

For your another question need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
print (df)
   0 name  number
0  1    a       3
1  2    a       6
2  2    a       8
3  3    b       2
4  4    b     500
5  4    b     600
6  5    c     349
7  6    c     200

df['diff'] = df.groupby('name')['number'].transform(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
print (df)
   0 name  number  diff
0  1    a       3     5
1  2    a       6     5
2  2    a       8     5
3  3    b       2   598
4  4    b     500   598
5  4    b     600   598
6  5    c     349   149
7  6    c     200   149
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby('name')['number'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min()).reset_index()
print (df)
  name  number
0    a       5
1    b     598
2    c     149
```

Comment: i am not sure if understand your second answer, can you explain more?

Comment: No you understood my question correctly. In the case of more than two sequentials rows with the same name, the highest number will be compared against the lowest instead. Thanks for the comprehensive answer.